# TypeScript expected `never` but got intersection

Tags: typescript, types, intersection, typescript-never

I was expecting a conflicting type intersection to produce a type of `never`. What am I missing?

```
type A = {value: string}
type B = {value: number}

type D = A & B

type E<T> = T extends never ? 'never' : 'something';
type F = E<D> // expected 'never', got 'something';
```

Comment: If you have an expectation that `{value: string} & {value: number}` is collapsed to `never`, could you [edit] to explain where that expectation comes from, maybe with an example where that does happen? TypeScript doesn't aggressively collapse all objects-with-`never` props to `never`.  It does do this specifically for discriminated unions, but that's not what's going on in the question, and I don't want to speculate about all possibly related language features; it would be nice to see something more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only the conflicting property that has the `never` type, not the entire object type `D` (other properties in the type [might be just fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeA3AhgGwK4QFxQGdgAnASwDsBzAGigA98iyqBfAKFEigCEFl1seKOSwBbAEYRi7DuGgARPnABkPNrK4BRADwAVAHx9dUCHWARyAEwLCIKKVAD8UAOTk7Ul1HwuCAe1EIYAALCkoXAG4NaAAxPh15fSiAemSodIA9R2ioGIAmeO15AG0AIgEcUoBdJLZU9Kgs9U5YgGY+EtK6aoioeu14RABVcjQAMzGIAGNzSyhxECgQ6AADCogVqDBiP3EMCFE6tMzHIA), after all). So `D["value"]` is `never`, but not `D`:

```typescript
type A = {value: string}
type B = {value: number}

type D = A & B

type E<T> = T extends never ? 'never' : 'something';
type F = E<D>;
//   ^?−− type F = "something"
type F2 = E<D["value"]>;
//   ^?−− type F2 = "never"
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeA3AhgGwK4QFxQGdgAnASwDsBzAXwChRIoAhBZdbPKcrAWwCMIxOvXDQAIqzgAyZrRGMAogB4AKgD5WKqBAAewCOQAmBLhBSCoAfigBycmcE2o+GwQD2PCMAAWFSjYBueWgAMVZlMTUggHpoqHiAPUtgqBCAJnClMQBtACJ2HFyAXSjaWPioJNogA)